# Expected best performance possible on a data set

Tags: machine-learning

Say I have a simple machine learning problem like a classification. With some benchmarks in vision or audio recognition, I, as a human, are a very good classifier. I therefore have an intuition on how good a classifier can get.

But with lots of data one point is that I *do not know* how good the classifier I train is possible to get. This is data where I personally am not a very good classifier (say, classify the mood of a person from EEG data). It is not really possible to get an intuition on how hard my problem is.

Now, if I am presented with a machine learning problem, I would like to find out  how good I can get. Are there any principled approaches to this? How would you do this?

Visualize data? Start with simple models? Start with very complex models and see if I can overfit? What are you looking for if you want to answer this question? When do you stop trying?

Answer (score 6):

I do not know whether this counts as an answer ...

This is the one problem which keeps you up at night. Do you can build a better model ? Phd-comics sums it up nicely (I don't know whether I am allowed to upload the comics, so I just linked them)

- [Proving the negative](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1194)
- [Conversation impossible](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1196)

From my personal experience, gained by participating in Machine Learning competitions, here is a rule of the thumb.

*Imagine you are given a classification task. Sit down, brainstorm an hour or less how you'd approach the problem and check out the state of the art in this area. Build a model based on this research, preferably one which is known to be stable without too much parameter tweaking. The resulting performance will be roughly around 80% of the maximum achievable performance.*

This rule is based on the so called [Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), which also applies to optimization. Given a problem, you can create a solution which performs reasonable well fast, but from that point the ratio of improvement to time effort drops rapidly.

Some final words: When I read papers about new classification algorithms, I expect the authors to compare their new breed with such "pareto-optimized" approaches, i.e. I expect them to spend a reasonable amount of time to make the state of the art work (some require more or less parameter optimization). Unfortunately, many don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way is to consider the ROC, and the [area under it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roc_curve#Area_Under_Curve) (AUC). The rationale behind this approach is that the higher the true positive rate for a particular false positive rate, the better the classifier. Integrating over all possible false positive rates gives you an overall measure.

Comment: As far as I have understood the OP, his issue is NOT the measuring of performance of a classifier (which is hopefully a good estimate for the future expected performance) but how good one can get AT ALL, i.e. what is the maximum (not absolutely per metric (AUC is 1 at max or something like that), but for a given problem)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If there is some way for you to visualize your data, that is the best possible scenario however not all data can be visualized in the same way, so you may need to find your own way to project the data that can help you understand your data better.

However, in general, I usually take a small sample of the data, convert it into ARFF and try different clustering algorithms from WEKA. Then, I just see which algorithm gives me better confusion matrix. It gives me a hint as to how well the classes are separated and allows me to investigate why that particular algorithm does better for this data. I also change the number of clusters (i.e i don't just use k = 2, I use k = 3, 4 etc.). It gives me an idea whether there is fragmentation in the data or whether one class is more fragmented than the other. If you mix training and testing points together for clustering, you can also measure which clusters are represented by your training points. Some clusters may be over-represented and some may be under-represented, both can cause issues which learning a classifier.

Always check your training accuracy. If your training accuracy is not looking good, then mis-classified training points are also a big hint.